# I have three queries linked to extract one table from oracle to SAS but the third one isnt coming out any output and i didnt find out the error

Tags: mysql, oracle, sas, extract

I am trying to extract one table from oracle to SAS by using the three interconnected queries belows, but the last one is not generating any output. I reviewd the code many times but i didnt find the error. Can you please help me?

First query

```
    %include "/sasusers/&sysuserid/gedspla.sas";
    libname Guik "/lidata_br/atuaria/dmatuarial/vida/GKK";
    %let produtos='93030', '93028', '77021', '77022', '77023', '77024', '77025', '77033', '77034', '77035', '77036', '77037', '77038', '77039', '77040', '77041', '77042';
    *%let meses=202003, 202002, 202001, 201912, 201911, 201910, 201909, 201908, 201907, 201906, 201905, 201904, 201903, 201902, 201901, 201812, 201811, 201810, 201809, 201808, 201807, 201806, 201805, 201804, 201803;
    %let meses=202003;

    proc sql ;
    connect to oracle(user=&d_usuario pass=&pass_dtm path='@dtm' preserve_comments);
        create table Guik.tabela1 (compress=yes reuse=yes) as
        select * from connection to oracle                              
    (

    select    a11.DCTI_DTON_COD_ATF  DTON_COD_ATF,
                  a11.DCTI_DDTC_COD_ATF  DDTC_COD_ATF,
                  a12.DHCT_TSPR_COD  DHCT_TSPR_COD,
                  a11.DCTI_DSDC_COD_ATF  DSDC_COD_ATF,
                  a11.DCTI_DDSC_COD_ATF  DDSC_COD_ATF,
                  a12.DHCT_IND_ROB  DHCT_IND_ROB,
                  a12.DHCT_NUM_PRA  DHCT_NUM_PRA,
                  a11.DCTI_DPRD_COD_PRD  DPRD_COD_PRD,
                  a12.DHCT_NUM_CTC  DHCT_NUM_CTC,
                  a12.DHCT_CTRS_COD  DHCT_CTRS_COD,
                  a12.DHCT_DCSN_MCL  DCSN_COD_ATF,
                  a12.DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC  DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC,
                  a11.DCTI_DMID_COD_ATF  DMID_COD_ATF,
                  a17.DFCL_DFFL_COD_ATF  DFFL_COD_ATF,
                  a11.DCTI_DCLD_RFR_COD_ATF  DCLD_COD_ATF,
                  a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_PRA  DCLD_COD_ATF0,
                  a12.DHCT_DCLD_PRI_RCU  DCLD_COD_ATF1,
                  a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC  DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC,
                  a11.DCTI_DCLD_INI_VGC_COD_ATF  DCLD_COD_ATF2,
                  a11.DCTI_DCLD_FIM_VGC_COD_ATF  DCLD_COD_ATF3,
                  a11.DCTI_DCLD_CRC_COD_ATF  DCLD_COD_ATF4,
                  a12.DHCT_DSIT_COD_ATF  DSIT_COD_ATF,
                  a11.DCTI_DCEP_COD_ATF  DCEP_COD_ATF,
                  a12.DHCT_NUM_APO  DMBE_APO_NUM,
                  sum(a11.DCTI_QTD_ITM)  WJXBFS1,
                  sum(a11.DCTI_MRI_NGC_CTC)  WJXBFS2
    from     
    DMD_ITM_CTC a11
    join       DMD_HIS_CTC a12 on (a11.DCTI_DHCT_COD_ATF = a12.DHCT_COD_ATF)
    join       DMD_HIS_CTC a13 on (a11.DCTI_DHCT_COD_ATF = a13.DHCT_COD_ATF and a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC = a13.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC and a12.DHCT_IND_ROB = a13.DHCT_IND_ROB)
    join       DMF_PRD     a14 on (a11.DCTI_DFPR_COD_ATF = a14.DFPR_COD_ATF)
    join       DMF_AGU_PRD a15 on (a14.DFPR_DFAP_COD_ATF = a15.DFAP_COD_ATF)
    join       DMC_CRT     a16 on (a12.DHCT_DCRT_COD_CLI_OPN_CRT = a16.DCRT_COD_CLI_OPN_CRT)
    join       DMF_CEL     a17 on (a16.DCRT_DFCL_COD_ATF = a17.DFCL_COD_ATF)
    where   
    (((a15.DFAP_DFCP_COD_ATF)           in (select  c21.DFCP_COD_ATF from DMF_CAT_PRD c21 where   c21.DFCP_DFSP_COD_ATF in (2426, 2430, 7781, 2427)))
    and TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMM')) in (&meses)
    and a11.DCTI_DPRD_COD_PRD           in (&produtos)
    and a12.DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC            in ('S')
    and a12.DHCT_DCRT_COD_CLI_OPN_CRT   not in (99040067))
    group by      a11.DCTI_DTON_COD_ATF,
                  a11.DCTI_DDTC_COD_ATF,
                  a12.DHCT_TSPR_COD,
                  a11.DCTI_DSDC_COD_ATF,
                  a11.DCTI_DDSC_COD_ATF,
                  a12.DHCT_IND_ROB,
                  a12.DHCT_NUM_PRA,
                  a11.DCTI_DPRD_COD_PRD,
                  a12.DHCT_NUM_CTC,
                  a12.DHCT_CTRS_COD,
                  a12.DHCT_DCSN_MCL,
                  a12.DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC,
                  a11.DCTI_DMID_COD_ATF,
                  a17.DFCL_DFFL_COD_ATF,
                  a11.DCTI_DCLD_RFR_COD_ATF,
                  a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_PRA,
                  a12.DHCT_DCLD_PRI_RCU,
                  a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC,
                  a11.DCTI_DCLD_INI_VGC_COD_ATF,
                  a11.DCTI_DCLD_FIM_VGC_COD_ATF,
                  a11.DCTI_DCLD_CRC_COD_ATF,
                  a12.DHCT_DSIT_COD_ATF,
                  a11.DCTI_DCEP_COD_ATF,
                  a12.DHCT_NUM_APO );
    ;
    disconnect from oracle;
    quit;
```

Second query

```
proc sql ;
connect to oracle(user=&d_usuario pass=&pass_dtm path='@dtm' preserve_comments);
    create table Guik.tabela2 (compress=yes reuse=yes) as
    select * from connection to oracle                              
(
select    a11.DCTI_DTON_COD_ATF  DTON_COD_ATF,
              a11.DCTI_DDTC_COD_ATF  DDTC_COD_ATF,
              a12.DHCT_TSPR_COD  DHCT_TSPR_COD,
              a11.DCTI_DSDC_COD_ATF  DSDC_COD_ATF,
              a11.DCTI_DDSC_COD_ATF  DDSC_COD_ATF,
              a12.DHCT_IND_ROB  DHCT_IND_ROB,
              a12.DHCT_NUM_PRA  DHCT_NUM_PRA,
              a11.DCTI_DPRD_COD_PRD  DPRD_COD_PRD,
              a12.DHCT_NUM_CTC  DHCT_NUM_CTC,
              a12.DHCT_CTRS_COD  DHCT_CTRS_COD,
              a12.DHCT_DCSN_MCL  DCSN_COD_ATF,
              a12.DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC  DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC,
              a11.DCTI_DMID_COD_ATF  DMID_COD_ATF,
              a17.DFCL_DFFL_COD_ATF  DFFL_COD_ATF,
              a11.DCTI_DCLD_RFR_COD_ATF  DCLD_COD_ATF,
              a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_PRA  DCLD_COD_ATF0,
              a12.DHCT_DCLD_PRI_RCU  DCLD_COD_ATF1,
              a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC  DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC,
              a11.DCTI_DCLD_INI_VGC_COD_ATF  DCLD_COD_ATF2,
              a11.DCTI_DCLD_FIM_VGC_COD_ATF  DCLD_COD_ATF3,
              a11.DCTI_DCLD_CRC_COD_ATF  DCLD_COD_ATF4,
              a12.DHCT_DSIT_COD_ATF  DSIT_COD_ATF,
              a11.DCTI_DCEP_COD_ATF  DCEP_COD_ATF,
              a12.DHCT_NUM_APO  DMBE_APO_NUM,
              sum(a11.DCTI_QTD_ITM)  WJXBFS1
from     DMD_ITM_CTC a11
              join       DMD_HIS_CTC a12
                on        (a11.DCTI_DHCT_COD_ATF = a12.DHCT_COD_ATF)
              join       DMD_HIS_CTC a13
                on        (a11.DCTI_DHCT_COD_ATF = a13.DHCT_COD_ATF and 
              a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC = a13.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC and 
              a12.DHCT_IND_ROB = a13.DHCT_IND_ROB)
              join       DMF_PRD          a14
                on        (a11.DCTI_DFPR_COD_ATF = a14.DFPR_COD_ATF)
              join       DMF_AGU_PRD              a15
                on        (a14.DFPR_DFAP_COD_ATF = a15.DFAP_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_CRT          a16
                on        (a12.DHCT_DCRT_COD_CLI_OPN_CRT = a16.DCRT_COD_CLI_OPN_CRT)
              join       DMF_CEL           a17
                on        (a16.DCRT_DFCL_COD_ATF = a17.DFCL_COD_ATF)
where   (((a15.DFAP_DFCP_COD_ATF)
in          (select  c21.DFCP_COD_ATF
              from     DMF_CAT_PRD c21
              where   c21.DFCP_DFSP_COD_ATF in (2426, 2430, 7781, 2427)))
and TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMM')) in (202003, 202002, 202001, 201912, 201911, 201910, 201909, 201908, 201907, 201906, 201905, 201904, 201903, 201902, 201901, 201812, 201811, 201810, 201809, 201808, 201807, 201806, 201805, 201804, 201803)
and a11.DCTI_DPRD_COD_PRD in ('93030', '93028', '77021', '77022', '77023', '77024', '77025', '77033', '77034', '77035', '77036', '77037', '77038', '77039', '77040', '77041', '77042')
and a12.DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC in ('S')
and a12.DHCT_DCRT_COD_CLI_OPN_CRT not in (99040067)
and a11.DCTI_DDSC_COD_ATF in (3))
group by            a11.DCTI_DTON_COD_ATF,
              a11.DCTI_DDTC_COD_ATF,
              a12.DHCT_TSPR_COD,
              a11.DCTI_DSDC_COD_ATF,
              a11.DCTI_DDSC_COD_ATF,
              a12.DHCT_IND_ROB,
              a12.DHCT_NUM_PRA,
              a11.DCTI_DPRD_COD_PRD,
              a12.DHCT_NUM_CTC,
              a12.DHCT_CTRS_COD,
              a12.DHCT_DCSN_MCL,
              a12.DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC,
              a11.DCTI_DMID_COD_ATF,
              a17.DFCL_DFFL_COD_ATF,
              a11.DCTI_DCLD_RFR_COD_ATF,
              a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_PRA,
              a12.DHCT_DCLD_PRI_RCU,
              a12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC,
              a11.DCTI_DCLD_INI_VGC_COD_ATF,
              a11.DCTI_DCLD_FIM_VGC_COD_ATF,
              a11.DCTI_DCLD_CRC_COD_ATF,
              a12.DHCT_DSIT_COD_ATF,
              a11.DCTI_DCEP_COD_ATF,
              a12.DHCT_NUM_APO )
;
disconnect from oracle;
quit;
```

Third query (the problem). 
OBS: It doesn't appear any error related to code in the log. Id doent appear anythhing. It runs normally.

```
proc sql ;
connect to oracle(user=&d_usuario pass=&pass_dtm path='@dtm' preserve_comments);
    create table Guik.tabela3 (compress=yes reuse=yes) as
    select * from connection to oracle                              
(
select  distinct coalesce(pa11.DHCT_NUM_CTC, pa12.DHCT_NUM_CTC)  DHCT_NUM_CTC,
              coalesce(pa11.DTON_COD_ATF, pa12.DTON_COD_ATF)  DTON_COD_ATF,
              FN_MSTR_CHR_SET(a121.DTON_DES)  DTON_DES,
              coalesce(pa11.DDTC_COD_ATF, pa12.DDTC_COD_ATF)  DDTC_COD_ATF,
              a120.DDTC_DES  DDTC_DES,
              coalesce(pa11.DDSC_COD_ATF, pa12.DDSC_COD_ATF)  DDSC_COD_ATF,
              FN_MSTR_CHR_SET(a117.DDSC_DES)  DDSC_DES,
              coalesce(pa11.DSDC_COD_ATF, pa12.DSDC_COD_ATF)  DSDC_COD_ATF,
              a118.DSDC_DES  DSDC_DES,
              coalesce(pa11.DHCT_NUM_PRA, pa12.DHCT_NUM_PRA)  DHCT_NUM_PRA,
              coalesce(pa11.DHCT_TSPR_COD, pa12.DHCT_TSPR_COD)  DHCT_TSPR_COD,
              a119.TSPR_DES  DHCT_TSPR_DES,
              coalesce(pa11.DCSN_COD_ATF, pa12.DCSN_COD_ATF)  DCSN_COD_ATF,
              a115.DCSN_COD_SOG  DCSN_COD_SOG,
              coalesce(pa11.DHCT_IND_ROB, pa12.DHCT_IND_ROB)  DHCT_IND_ROB,
              coalesce(pa11.DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC, pa12.DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC)  DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC,
              coalesce(pa11.DMID_COD_ATF, pa12.DMID_COD_ATF)  DMID_COD_ATF,
               a114.DMID_DES  DMID_DES,
              coalesce(pa11.DSIT_COD_ATF, pa12.DSIT_COD_ATF)  DSIT_COD_ATF,
              a17.DSIT_DES  DSIT_DES,
              coalesce(pa11.DMBE_APO_NUM, pa12.DMBE_APO_NUM)  DMBE_APO_NUM,
              coalesce(pa11.DHCT_CTRS_COD, pa12.DHCT_CTRS_COD)  DHCT_CTRS_COD,
              coalesce(pa11.DCEP_COD_ATF, pa12.DCEP_COD_ATF)  DCEP_COD_ATF,
              a16.DCEP_COD_CEP_REZ  DCEP_COD_CEP_REZ,
              coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF)  DCLD_COD_ATF,
              a113.DCLD_DAT  DCLD_DAT,
              coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF0, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF0)  DCLD_COD_ATF0,
              a112.DCLD_DAT  DCLD_DAT0,
              coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF1, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF1)  DCLD_COD_ATF1,
              a111.DCLD_DAT  DCLD_DAT1,
              coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF2, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF2)  DCLD_COD_ATF2,
              a110.DCLD_DAT  DCLD_DAT2,
              coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF3, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF3)  DCLD_COD_ATF3,
              a19.DCLD_DAT  DCLD_DAT3,
              coalesce(pa11.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC, pa12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC)  DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC,
              a14.DCLD_DAT  DCLD_DAT4,
              coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF4, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF4)  DCLD_COD_ATF4,
              a18.DCLD_DAT  DCLD_DAT5,
              coalesce(pa11.DPRD_COD_PRD, pa12.DPRD_COD_PRD)  DPRD_COD_PRD,
              FN_MSTR_CHR_SET(a116.DPRD_NOM)  DPRD_NOM,
              a15.DFFL_DFRG_COD_ATF  DFRG_COD_ATF,
              FN_MSTR_CHR_SET(a123.DFRG_DES)  DFRG_DES,
              a14.DCLD_DMAN_COD_ATF  DMAN_COD_ATF,
              a122.DMAN_DES  DMAN_DES,
              coalesce(pa11.DFFL_COD_ATF, pa12.DFFL_COD_ATF)  DFFL_COD_ATF,
              FN_MSTR_CHR _SET(a15.DFFL_DES)  DFFL_DES,
              pa11.WJXBFS1  WJXBFS1,
              pa12.WJXBFS1  WJXBFS2,
              pa11.WJXBFS2  WJXBFS3
from     Guik.tabela1    pa11

              full outer join    Guik.tabela2  pa12 on (pa11.DCEP_COD_ATF = pa12.DCEP_COD_ATF and 
              pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF = pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF and 
              pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF0 = pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF0 and 
              pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF1 = pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF1 and 
              pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF2 = pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF2 and 
              pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF3 = pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF3 and 
              pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF4 = pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF4 and 
              pa11.DCSN_COD_ATF = pa12.DCSN_COD_ATF and 
              pa11.DDSC_COD_ATF = pa12.DDSC_COD_ATF and 
              pa11.DDTC_COD_ATF = pa12.DDTC_COD_ATF and 
              pa11.DFFL_COD_ATF = pa12.DFFL_COD_ATF and 
              pa11.DHCT_CTRS_COD = pa12.DHCT_CTRS_COD and 
              pa11.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC = pa12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC and 
              pa11.DHCT_IND_ROB = pa12.DHCT_IND_ROB and 
              pa11.DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC = pa12.DHCT_IND_ULT_CTC and 
              pa11.DHCT_NUM_CTC = pa12.DHCT_NUM_CTC and 
              pa11.DHCT_NUM_PRA = pa12.DHCT_NUM_PRA and 
              pa11.DHCT_TSPR_COD = pa12.DHCT_TSPR_COD and 
              pa11.DMBE_APO_NUM = pa12.DMBE_APO_NUM and 
              pa11.DMID_COD_ATF = pa12.DMID_COD_ATF and 
              pa11.DPRD_COD_PRD = pa12.DPRD_COD_PRD and 
              pa11.DSDC_COD_ATF = pa12.DSDC_COD_ATF and 
              pa11.DSIT_COD_ATF = pa12.DSIT_COD_ATF and 
              pa11.DTON_COD_ATF = pa12.DTON_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_CLD     a14  on        (coalesce(pa11.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC, pa12.DHCT_DCLD_DAT_CTC) = a14.DCLD_COD_ATF)
              join       DMF_FIL     a15  on        (coalesce(pa11.DFFL_COD_ATF, pa12.DFFL_COD_ATF) = a15.DFFL_COD_ATF)
              join       DMM_CEP     a16  on        (coalesce(pa11.DCEP_COD_ATF, pa12.DCEP_COD_ATF) = a16.DCEP_COD_ATF)
              join       DMD_STM_ORI a17  on        (coalesce(pa11.DSIT_COD_ATF, pa12.DSIT_COD_ATF) = a17.DSIT_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_CLD     a18  on        (coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF4, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF4) = a18.DCLD_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_CLD     a19  on        (coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF3, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF3) = a19.DCLD_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_CLD     a110 on        (coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF2, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF2) = a110.DCLD_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_CLD     a111 on        (coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF1, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF1) = a111.DCLD_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_CLD     a112 on        (coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF0, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF0) = a112.DCLD_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_CLD     a113 on        (coalesce(pa11.DCLD_COD_ATF, pa12.DCLD_COD_ATF) = a113.DCLD_COD_ATF)
              join       DMM_IDD     a114 on        (coalesce(pa11.DMID_COD_ATF, pa12.DMID_COD_ATF) = a114.DMID_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_SIM_NAO a115 on        (coalesce(pa11.DCSN_COD_ATF, pa12.DCSN_COD_ATF) = a115.DCSN_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_PRD     a116 on        (coalesce(pa11.DPRD_COD_PRD, pa12.DPRD_COD_PRD) = a116.DPRD_COD_PRD)
              join       DMD_STS_CTC a117 on        (coalesce(pa11.DDSC_COD_ATF, pa12.DDSC_COD_ATF) = a117.DDSC_COD_ATF)
              join       DMD_STS_DTL_CTC a118 on   (coalesce(pa11.DSDC_COD_ATF, pa12.DSDC_COD_ATF) = a118.DSDC_COD_ATF)
              join       (SELECT distinct DHCT_TSPR_COD TSPR_COD,
                                DHCT_TSPR_DES TSPR_DES
FROM DMD_HIS_CTC)  a119 on        (coalesce(pa11.DHCT_TSPR_COD, pa12.DHCT_TSPR_COD) = a119.TSPR_COD)
              join       DMD_TIP_CTC  a120  on        (coalesce(pa11.DDTC_COD_ATF, pa12.DDTC_COD_ATF) = a120.DDTC_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_TIP_ORI_NGC       a121 on        (coalesce(pa11.DTON_COD_ATF, pa12.DTON_COD_ATF) = a121.DTON_COD_ATF)
              join       DMC_MES_ANO             a122 on        (a14.DCLD_DMAN_COD_ATF = a122.DMAN_COD_ATF)
              join       DMF_RGI           a123 on        (a15.DFFL_DFRG_COD_ATF = a123.DFRG_COD_ATF)

;
disconnect from oracle;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The third query does not have a closing parenthesis for `from connection to oracle`

Try

```
... 
              join       DMF_RGI           a123 on        (a15.DFFL_DFRG_COD_ATF = a123.DFRG_COD_ATF)

)  /* -------- Add this is the missing piece */

;
disconnect from oracle;
quit;
```